# Android Studio Fabric Plugin displays wrong characters - the weirdest bug

Tags: android-studio, plugins, google-fabric

I have the weirdest display bug in the Fabric Plugin for Android Studio.
Check it out :

[image: fabric plugin character bug]

Interestingly :

- I discovered that each and every character was replaced by its ASCII value minus 2. Ex : "2 PEOPLE" is displayed "0 NCMNJC".
- Characters are weirdly overlapping each other. As the typeface is not monospace ('m' takes more space than 'i'), it indicates that the required space for each character is rightfully calculated, but the wrong character is finally displayed.

Any idea ?

I'm running Android Studio 2.3.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: On Which OS are you running Android Studio ?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - that's a strange one I haven't seen before. Perhaps logging out of the plugin using Ctrl+L or a restart of AS might fix it?

Comment: No it was a Windows + broken font problem, strangely affecting only the Fabric plugin...

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a much wider problem I solved by deleting hundreds of fonts following  [that piece of advice](https://superuser.com/questions/959710/why-is-my-windows-10-system-replacing-system-font-typically-a-sans-serif-like-a)

I don't know which font was causing this and why it only affected this particular plugin of this particular software though.

Answer (score 0):

i'm running windows 7 and run into the same problem what worked for me is :

startMenu>control panel>

top right on control panel window choosing any other view than category >

choose fonts folder>
in the fonts window on the top left choose font setting
and than press the restore default font setting

after all this restart your computer and than you should see the right font displayed also note that i did a full uninstall and reinstall of the fabric.io plugin to android studio before restarting computer cause when i reset the font setting it caused a quick display of the right font and than jumped to the bugged font all over...